MySQL Stored Procedure slower than direct query
I have a query that runs in <1s when run directly in MySQL workbench, but is non-performant when run as a Stored Procedure or via the Event Scheduler.
Simplified Table Definition:
CREATE TABLE `tbl_s` (
  `host_id` tinyint NOT NULL,
  `AuditTime_eastern` datetime(6) NOT NULL,
  `UserId` char(3) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin NOT NULL,
  `AuditDate_eastern` date NOT NULL,
  `AppointmentId_old` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `AppointmentId_new` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `StartTime_eastern_old` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `StartTime_eastern_new` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`host_id`,`AuditTime_eastern`,`UserId`),
  KEY `IX1` (`host_id`,`AuditDate_eastern`,`AppointmentTypeId_old`,`AppointmentTypeId_new`,`StartTime_eastern_old`,`StartTime_eastern_new`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_bin;

serverVersion=8.0.36
tbl_s has 6.2M rows currently
Query:
SELECT 
    s1.appointmentid_old, s2.appointmentid_new
FROM
     tbl_s as s1
        LEFT JOIN
     tbl_s as s2 ON
             s1.host_id = s2.host_id
         AND s1.StartTime_eastern_old = s2.StartTime_eastern_new
         AND s2.Auditdate_eastern >= '2024-09-14'
   WHERE
            s1.auditdate_eastern >= '2024-09-14'
        AND s1.host_id = 1
        AND s1.AppointmentTypeId_old = 2

The explain for the query when run directly returns:
id, select_type, table, type, possible_keys, key, key_len, ref, rows, Extra
1, SIMPLE, s1, , range, PRIMARY,IX1, IX1, 9, , 493, 10.00, Using index condition
1, SIMPLE, s2, , range, PRIMARY,IX1, IX1, 4, , 634, 100.00, Using where; Using join buffer (hash join)

The explain for the query when run as a stored procedure returns:
id, select_type, table, type, possible_keys, key, key_len, ref, rows, Extra
1, SIMPLE, s1, , range, PRIMARY,IX1, IX1. 9, , 493, 10.00, Using index condition
1, SIMPLE, s2, , ref, PRIMARY,IX1, PRIMARY, 1, const, 1391, 100.00, Using where

Clearly the stored procedure is not naturally using IX1 for S2. When I add a USE INDEX (IX1) to the join, the stored procedure explain returns:
id, select_type, table, type, possible_keys, key, key_len, ref, rows, Extra
1, SIMPLE, s1, , range, PRIMARY,IX1, IX1, 9, , 493, 10.00, Using index condition
1, SIMPLE, s2, , ref, IX1, IX1, 1, const, 2358, 100.00, Using where

I've read about similar issues being caused by differing collations, but I don't think that's the culprit here since we're not really using any text fields.
A couple additional notes:

The date of '2024-09-14' is chosen for troubleshooting purposes, and the actual requirement is an earlier static date
My ultimate goal is to use this as the basis for an Event Scheduler based Insert, but I've simplified the problem down to the above.

What can I do to get the stored procedure to perform similarly to the direct query?

If you change the layout of the explain results to the same way as you do with the queries, they will probably be a lot easier to read.

You should move StartTime_eastern_old and StartTime_eastern_new earlier in the index. It's best for columns that are compared with < and > to be after the ones that are tested with =.

@Barmar thanks for the suggestion. I tried a couple permutations of moving these up in the index and generally see worse performance. I've observed that if Auditdate_eastern is not in the 1st or 2nd spot of the index, the direct query does not make use of the hash join and the performance degrades substantially as a result.

workbench lies to you.  it often adds a limit clause.  try the command line client

@ysth the direct query performance is not row limited in MySQL workbench and produces and fetches the full result set

What are the parameters to the Stored proc?

@RickJames - the stored proc has no parameters. It just runs the verbatim query provided above. My ultimate goal is to run this query efficiently via the event scheduler, which has similarly poor performance as the stored procedure. I'm using the stored procedure as a troubleshooting step, since it's much easier to test than the event scheduler and can easily produce an EXPLAIN statement.

Please provide SHOW CREATE TABLE tbl_s.
These will probably help:
INDEX(host_id, AppointmentTypeId_old,  -- either order is OK
      auditdate_eastern,               -- next because of "range"
      StartTime_eastern_old)           -- "covering"
INDEX(host_id, StartTime_eastern_new, Auditdate_eastern)


Are you asking for something different than the Simplified Table Definition provided at the top of the post? The only difference between the simplification I provided and the full SHOW CREATE TABLE is the sanitized table name and a bunch of unused fields that I removed for readability.

The order of columns in an INDEX is important.  = tests should come before "range" tests.  More:  Index Cookbook

"unused fields removed..." -- If you removed anything from the WHERE or ON clauses, my advice is likely to be incorrect.

I understand why tweaking the index order may improve overall performance, but does that explain the different performance I'm seeing between direct queries and stored procedure?
From testing different index field orders, I've observed if Auditdate_eastern is not in the 1st or 2nd spot of the index, the direct query does not make use of the hash join and the performance degrades substantially as a result
And no, none of the 'unused fields' that were omitted from the table definition are used or referenced in anyway in the query I'm troubleshooting.

@BigAlDente - I don't know why performance degrades, but maybe the indexes will prevent it.
